# phonegap singlepage jquery slide function to change html document?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, slide, singlepage

i currently am developing a phonegap application. When i change to another menu i do it like this:

```
$('#newMenu').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
```

The menu element that is shown is a positioned absolute element on top of the html body. I really like the slide feature and would like to use this for all my menus when i change beetween them, however is it possible use this feature to change the entire html page? Otherwise i doomed to develop a single page html app, right?? I mean, if i on the newMenu want to go to another menu, then i would have to do the same thing again, with another positioned absolute element on top. This means i have to develop it all as a single page layout and i think that will get messy..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the entire html page using the changePage function of jquerymobile like this

$.mobile.changePage( "index2.html", {
    transition: "slide"
});

Comment: Thats fine but what i really need is to see some "touch/click event-code" on the elements inside the scrollable div.